# How to check if orders which were pending the last time you check if they are completed? -- Paypal

Tags: paypal

I first check straight after the order is made if it is completed, if so I update some stuff. But then I want to check if all orders which weren't completed immediately are completed now.

Does someone has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

with paypal you should create a listening class or script that will be called by the paypal api ayntime something new happened like a completed purchase. check their API for their IPN.

I found this tutorial

http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html